# Bash: All combinations of variables

Tags: bash, unix, combinations

I want to generate all the combinations of a set of variables.

I ended up with the following:

```
a="A"
b="B"
c="C"
d="D"
e="E"
f="F"

echo {$a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f} $a{$b,$c,$d,$e,$f} $b{$c,$d,$e,$f} $c{$d,$e,$f} $d{$e,$f} $e$f $a$b{$c,$d,$e,$f} $b$c{$d,$e,$f} $c$d{$e,$f} $d$e$f $a$b$c$d{$e,$f} $b$c$d$e$f $a$b$c$d$e$f
```

This generates the following output:

```
A B C D E F AB AC AD AE AF BC BD BE BF CD CE CF DE DF EF ABC ABD ABE ABF BCD BCE BCF CDE CDF DEF ABCDE ABCDF BCDEF ABCDEF
```

Is there a more concise and elegant way of doing this in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the script

```
echo {'','a'}{'','b'}{'','c'}{'','d'}{'','e'}{'','f'}
```

you will get

```
 f e ef d df de def c cf ce cef cd cdf cde cdef b bf be bef bd bdf bde bdef bc bcf bce bcef bcd bcdf bcde bcdef a af ae aef ad adf ade adef ac acf ace acef acd acdf acde acdef ab abf abe abef abd abdf abde abdef abc abcf abce abcef abcd abcdf abcde abcdef
```

Though not in order, this does what you may want. So you can use

```
echo {'',$a}{'',$b}{'',$c}{'',$d}{'',$e}{'',$f}
```

If you do not wish to type so many `{'',$x}` in the script you may even use `eval`:

```
eval `echo echo "{'',$"{a..f}"}" | sed 's/ //2g'`
```